# PHP Zip File Empty?

Tags: php

I have a script that creates a zip files from files in a certain directory. After Download, for a lot of users - the zip file is empty. However, for other users - the file isn't empty. Is it something I'm doing wrong?

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$id.'.zip"');
header('Cache-Control: private');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("".$id.".zip");
exit;
```

Comment: Does the problem correlate to filenames?  (e.g. with quotes or spaces or other special chars)

Comment: Does `$id` differ between users? Better ask them for the filename when they got an empty file.

Comment: By the way, is `$id` being sanitized properly? That seems like it would be very very easy to exploit.

Comment: I would consider implementing some logging in the event filesize($id . '.zip') is 0.

Comment: implement hashing of the files to make sure that the file makes it

Answer (score 1):

Better add some error control:

```
$file = "{$id}.zip";
if (!is_readable($file))
{
    die('Not accessible.');
}
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Additionally triple check your output buffering configuration vs. `readfile`.

Comment: I am not sold on the file_exists check, it does not account for situations like when the file_exists but does not have read permission, there are race conditons, etc.  I would suggest a streaming solution that uses fopen prior to setting the headers.

Comment: There is as well [`is_readable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php), true, changed.

Comment: There are still race conditions, like a process removing the file after the is_readable check but before readfile.  Using fopen prior to the header prevents this, even if the file is removed from the allocation table, it will still be readable while the resource exists.

Comment: why did you use curly brackets inside double quotes ??

Comment: To make it more visible that there is a variable. `"$zip.zip"` does work as well, but it's not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended this as a suggestion earlier, here is a skeleton of what I am talking about.  It is untested as I don't have access to php at the moment.

```
$filename = $id . '.zip';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
if ($handle === false)
{
    die('Could not read file "' . $filename . '"');
}

header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private');
while (!feof($handle))
{
    echo fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
exit;
```

Comment: As you like the handle, I suggest you use [`fpassthru()`](http://php.net/fpassthru) instead of looping over the file.